# Building computer desk with Solid core door (Help please)

Tags: wood, table, desk

if you're reading this I thank you for taking the time!

I am a beginner at this type of stuff but I know how to use saws and make cuts.

To cut to the chase, I am trying to build a nice and sturdy computer desk.
I bought a Birch, solid core door slab fresh from a lumber store. 80in by 36in and it is 1 and 7/8 thick. ( this thing is really heavy)

I am planning to use 4x4's for the legs, roughly 30 inches tall. But I do not know what or how to build a good strong sturdy support system underneath that can handle the load of the door slab plus 3, 32 inch monitors. Any advice, links to designs, or anything you can give me will be very much appreciated!

I am in the process of sanding and staining the door in the mean time.

Comment: You might want to do a search for `multi-monitor support` to see what sort of things work for supporting those monitors. Their weight will be negligible compared to the door. 4x4s will be overkill, so I guess that you are using them for the look. What you will need to take care of is resistance to lateral forces, so some sort of triangulation to affix the rear legs would be in order.

Comment: While this i a good question for here i would vote to move it to the **woodworking stack**. I would also think that this question is very broad, *There are many many ways to do this. here is one idea*.  -  http://www.ana-white.com/2013/09/plans/4x4-truss-beam-table  also research **woodworking Joinery**

Comment: Buy two two-drawer file cabinets. Set slab on top, done. There are a multitude of classic designs (allow your design search to span tables and workbenches as well as desks if you really want to build it) this happens to be the easiest and quickest one that comes to mind, and you can always replace it with something fancier later if you want to.